# Drupal 6: Changing content after a date has passed

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

Basically, I've got a client that wants these things:

- The ability to create events (specifying name, description, date, etc.). That's no problem - I'm familiar with Views (albeit in Drupal 7, but I can figure it out in 6)
- These events are going to be organized by date, essentially, past events will be put on their own page once the date of the event has actually passed.
- In addition to this, when the event date passes, the layout of the node will change, and any photos that have been uploaded will be visible to the viewer.

Now I know there are arguments in Views that pertain to date. An idea (that I literally JUST got):

- make two different views - one for past events and one for future events (pulling in only content from the 'event' content type, of course) and pass arguments for each of them, saying that if the date has passed, put them in the 'Past Events' view, and vice-versa for Future events.

Anyway, is this do-able in views or should I be getting another module? I've thought about the Rules Module but I'm unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Sounds right, on your view simply create a new display, one display is for future events and one for past events, change the layout (template) or the fields (easier) for the display and the date filter will be the one to use to decide when the display should show.

You could use the context module or even the rules module to decide which url to go to if your view uses pages, but if your using blocks then the date filter will be sufficient.